# What does "invalid file flags in class" mean?

Tags: android, dalvik

I'm trying to deploy a simple Android app, and it's giving me a INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error.  When I check logcat, I get the following:

```
W/dalvikvm( 5558): Invalid file flags in class <class from my app>;: 0012
```

So what does "invalid file flags in class" mean, and does the value 0012 have anything to do with anything?  I tried running some Google searches but didn't come up with much of anything; all I find are error reports with this line in it, but no explanation of what's going wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: What's the logcat say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this (dalvik/vm/oo/Class.cpp):

```
/*
 * Make sure the aren't any "bonus" flags set, since we use them for
 * runtime state.
 */
/* bits we can reasonably expect to see set in a DEX access flags field */
const uint32_t EXPECTED_FILE_FLAGS = (ACC_CLASS_MASK | CLASS_ISPREVERIFIED |
                                      CLASS_ISOPTIMIZED);
if ((pClassDef->accessFlags & ~EXPECTED_FILE_FLAGS) != 0) {
    ALOGW("Invalid file flags in class %s: %04x",
        descriptor, pClassDef->accessFlags);
    return NULL;
}
```

The error message indicates that your class has flags 0x0012 set; these are `ACC_FINAL` and `ACC_PRIVATE`.  `ACC_CLASS_MASK`, defined in dalvik/libdex/DexFile.h, does not include `ACC_PRIVATE`:

```
ACC_CLASS_MASK =
    (ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_FINAL | ACC_INTERFACE | ACC_ABSTRACT
            | ACC_SYNTHETIC | ACC_ANNOTATION | ACC_ENUM),
```

The `ACC_INNER_CLASS_MASK` includes private, protected, and static, but these are not appropriate for an "outer" class.

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be the problem.  The class in question was an inner class when it shouldn't have been.